# JSF 2 validators can't use "var" from dataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2, validation, custom-validators

We've recently upgraded our systems from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 and are in the process of making everything work. However, we're experiencing problems with validators, when used inside data tables or similar components. Basically, the problem is that the validator can't use the variable set by the data table.

Here's an example:

VALIDATOR:

```
package test;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("test.TestValidator")
public class TestValidator implements Validator {

    private Integer length;

    public TestValidator() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context,
            UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        String text = (String) value;
        if (text == null || text.trim().length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (length != null && text != null && length.intValue() < text.length()) {
            String message = "The text is too long. It was " + text.length() +
                    ", but only " + length + " characters are allowed.";
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null);
            throw new ValidatorException(fm);
        }
    }

    public Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(Integer length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

TAGLIB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <facelet-taglib
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
        <namespace>http://industry-supply.dk/test</namespace>
        <tag>
            <tag-name>testValidator</tag-name>
            <validator>
                <validator-id>test.TestValidator</validator-id>
            </validator>
            <attribute>
                <name>length</name>
                <required>true</required>
                <type>java.lang.Integer</type>
            </attribute>
        </tag>
    </facelet-taglib>
```

MANAGED BEAN:

```
package test;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

    public TestBean() {
    }

    public String[] getKey() {
        return new String[]{
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                };
    }

    public String[] getValue() {
        return new String[]{
                    "This is a text and it's too long.",
                    "This is a text and it's too long.",
                    "This is a text and it's too long.",
                    "This is a text and it's too long."
                };
    }
}
```

JSF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:test="http://industry-supply.dk/test">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{testBean.key}" var="k">
                <h:column>
                    <h:message for="val"/>
                    <h:inputText id="val" value="#{testBean.value[k]}">
                        <test:testValidator length="#{testBean.key[k]}"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When running the project, 4 input fields and a command button are shown. Each input field contains a 33 character long text. When you click "submit", the error message "The text is too long. It was 33, but only 0 characters are allowed." is shown for each row/field. This is wrong, because "test:testValidator length="#{testBean.key[k]}"" specifies length to 0 for the first row, 1 for the second row, 2 for the third row and 3 for the fourth row. So for the last row, the error message should have said: "The text is too long. It was 33, but only 3 characters are allowed.".

The problem is that the validator doesn't seem to have access to the k-variable from the dataTable component in the JSF file. This worked in JSF 1.2, but we can't get it to work in JSF 2.0. We've spend days on the problem now and really need some help. Ideas anyone?

Comment: I feel maybe I should specify the problem a bit more. It seems that the validator's length is set with the integer resolved from the expression #{testBean.key[k]} in the beginning of the request, but later in the request when the dataTable iterates, the expression isn't resolved again nor is length set again. Since k is only set during the dataTables iterations, this means length stays null throughout the entire request. The perfect solution would be if the expression could get resolved once per iteration, but I don't know how to force this.

Comment: I didn't see this comment when I was writing my answer, but see my remarks about `ValueExpressions`. You will have to evaluate the expression in the validator (you can get the `ELContext` from the `FacesContext`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your validator has a bug in it and you were just getting lucky under previous implementations.

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html):

> ...if the `Validator` class wishes to have configuration property values saved and restored with the view, the implementation must also implement [`StateHolder`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html).

When the view is restored during the POST operation the length state may no longer be present.

*I don't remember what happens with ValueExpressions on validators - unlike components, validators tend not to have [binding maps](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression%28java.lang.String%2C%20javax.el.ValueExpression%29) to hold them in. You may have to create your own [ValidatorHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/ValidatorHandler.html) or something - I haven't looked at this part of the API in detail.*

Comment: I've tried implementing StateHolder and even PartialStateHolder. It doesn't seem to make any difference. As I see it, the problem is that we're switching from JSP to Facelets and are changing our components, converters and validators so they no longer have a tag file. Previously we had a tag file taking ValueExpressions and setting the component. But with Facelets we don't have the tag file anymore. Instead the component/converter/validator is set directly, and is set with the resolved expression. Not the expression itself. This means we can't re-resolve the expression.

Comment: I think I will try to look into using a ValidatorHandler, as you suggest. I will post back with the results, but I'm open to more suggestions in the meantime.

Comment: @Bjørn Stenfeldt - thanks for posting your solution - interesting. I would still implement StateHolder as per the class contract. I'm guessing that your views are being held in session RAM; if you ever switched state saving mechanism your class might break. This may not be a risk for you however.

Comment: You're right, and by default we usually implement StateHolder. However, I decided to exclude it from the example to reduce the size of the posted code. Not having it, didn't seem to have any effect in the example. It's possible that was just luck, so anyone copying this example might want to be aware of this, if they make changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it seems everything is working now. I've created a custom ValidatorHandler, as suggested by McDowell. Here are my changes:

TAGLIB:

```
<handler-class>test.CustomValidatorHandler</handler-class>
```

VALIDATOR:

```
package test;

import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("test.TestValidator")
public class TestValidator implements Validator {

    public TestValidator() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context,
            UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        String text = (String) value;
        if (text == null || text.trim().length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Integer length = getLengthValue();

        if (length != null && text != null && length.intValue() < text.length()) {
            String message = "The text is too long. It was " + text.length() +
                    ", but only " + length + " characters are allowed.";
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null);
            throw new ValidatorException(fm);
        }
    }

    private ValueExpression lengthExpression;

    public ValueExpression getLength() {
        return lengthExpression;
    }

    public void setLength(ValueExpression length) {
        this.lengthExpression = length;
    }

    public Integer getLengthValue() {
        Integer length = null;
        if (lengthExpression != null) {
            length = (Integer) lengthExpression.getValue(
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
        }
        return length;
    }
}
```

VALIDATOR HANDLER:

```
package test;

import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ValidatorConfig;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.ValidatorHandler;

public class CustomValidatorHandler extends ValidatorHandler {

    private ValueExpression lengthExpression;

    public CustomValidatorHandler(ValidatorConfig config) {
        super(config);
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) facesContext.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
        lengthExpression = config.getTag().getAttributes().get("length").getValueExpression(faceletContext, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttributes(FaceletContext ctx, Object instance) {
//        super.setAttributes(ctx, instance);
        if (instance instanceof TestValidator) {
            TestValidator validator = (TestValidator) instance;
            validator.setLength(lengthExpression);
        }
    }
}
```